# Jekyll pagination only working locally, not working on live server

Tags: github, jekyll

I've been playing around with Jekyll and locally everything works fine. However once pushed to Github and run from Gitpages, the pagination for my posts page doesn't work properly. It's paginating the page. I get a next arrow, but once clicked you stay on the same page, so i guess it's not generating the pages correctly.

My config looks like:

```
name: Sitename
description: "A description of your site"

root: /
permalink: /posts/:year/:month/:day/:title
markdown: redcarpet
pygments: true

paginate: 8          # Posts per page on the blog index
paginate_path: "posts/page:num"

navigation:
- text: Posts
  url: /posts/
- text: Archive
  url: /archive/
- text: About
  url: /about/
```

Do i need to set my root to something different for running off Github? I have tried

```
https://github.com/username/projectname.github.io
```

However still nothing works. Help appreciated. Ive also checked i am running the latest version of Jekyll.

Link to my repo: https://github.com/vdecree/vdecree.github.io

Comment: I'd check you're using the latest version of Jekyll (run `sudo gem update jekyll` in a terminal). Posting a link to your repository on github might help us find the problem.

Comment: Of course ill update question with a link

Comment: http://vdecree.github.io redirects to http://visualdecree.co.uk
and seems working. right?

Comment: I found the fault, i will update with an answer for the small chance someone will make the same mistake as me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the reason pagination failed to build properly was due to a custom rakefile i was using. It was to help auto publish my site. The custom file i used was from: http://ixti.net/software/2013/01/28/using-jekyll-plugins-on-github-pages.html#comment-1057502074

I'm looking into what exactly caused the problem, but for anyone - however unlikely - that uses this same rakefile, i will try and post my findings.